# How to create custom events with the new Google Analytics 4 in React Native?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

How to work with GA4 in a react native app? The popular react-native libraries support the older GA version only.

I'd like to support Custom events and also set page_view title.

Could you share an example? Library I can use?

All I could find are implementations of the old analytics or implementation that does not show how to create custom events.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK is the recommended method to track iOS and Android apps.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4

You can use this awesome library `@react-native-firebase/analytics` https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#custom-events and collect analytics events into Google Analytics